# Identify circles with hough circle

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition, hough-transform

I am using opencv and C++..I have a face with different colors of circular marker points. I am using hough circle to identify those circles. My problem is that i am not able to understand the different parameters of the Hough function so that it identifies all the marker points.

http://www.google.mu/imgres?safe=off&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=mNIRfBLT-iJgXM:&imgrefurl=http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-ypaa-jmm2006.pdf&docid=KS8xrFEhIj5qnM&imgurl=x-raw-image:///22fad3127c11d298b93841a20820c1da82cc4a67fa4e8bb352cfb91669f0abdd&w=320&h=240&ei=mG1dUtW7BojMrQe0vYHIDQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:6,s:0,i:94&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=186&tbnw=247&start=0&ndsp=17&tx=97&ty=62

Thanks

Comment: What function are you calling?

Comment: i am using the HoughCircles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles

It gives the parameters of the function HoughCircles. Do you need more of an explanation of any parameters?

Comment: yes thanks..but i am trying out all the combinations but it cant detect exactly those marker points..it either detects more or detects only the pupils of that face :/

Comment: Try looking at the Canny edge map with the same parameters, and see if the circles are even visible there. Once you have the parameters to Canny working well enough, the Hough transform will be more likely to work.

Comment: but the canny edge map does not have the same parameters,right? how will i be able to compare those 2?

Comment: Two of the parameters to HoughCircles are simply passed through to Canny.

Comment: Also, given the size of the circles and the fact that some of them will be skewed, the Hough transform is probably not a very good choice. You would probably do better to look for the specific colors of the markers.

Comment: so i do a color segmentation and then apply hough transform?